# Do the 2022 FIFA World Cup ball sensors track the ball's location, and if so, how accurate is it?

Tags: football, world-cup, video-review, technology

Follow-up of [Why was Japan's second goal deemed to be valid?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/28518/1832): do the 2022 FIFA World Cup ball sensors track the ball's location, and if so, how accurate is it?

Comment: A lot of this is answered [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/28503/6126); I suspect you won't get a real answer to "how accurate is it" other than Adidas's marketing materials.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/28503/1832:

> [From the manufacturer, Adidas](https://news.adidas.com/football/adidas-reveals-the-first-fifa-world-cup--official-match-ball-featuring-connected-ball-technology/s/cccb7187-a67c-4166-b57d-2b28f1d36fa0):
>
> > - Connected ball technology comes to Al Rihla for sport’s biggest stage, providing the VAR team with precise ball data in real time to support fast and accurate offside calls

However, this [tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/FIFAcom/status/1598702362243104768?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1598702362243104768%7Ctwgr%5Eddb8d45507cc76312f1a93a6c554ad1e932e76e8%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.espn.com%2Fsoccer%2Ffifa-world-cup%2Fstory%2F4822287%2Fwhy-japans-winning-goal-vs-spain-was-awarded-by-the-var) on the 2022 FIFA World Cup match between Japan and Spain shows the video that match officials used the goal line camera images to check whether the ball was still partially on the line. But no ball sensors are mentioned.